How to return all value from a column column in Microsoft list that allows for multiple choices
I have a flow that sends an email with data from my list. However, my program data returns no values even though i have 2 choices selected "blue" and "red". When it is only one selection, the email will have the data but not when their is 2 choices. I use the dyanmic contect function in the email "program value" to reuten the value.
I tried to initalize variable to store all the choices but all that did was send an email with all the choices not the ones i selected

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

if your choice column allows multiple choice, the PowerAutomate will put the email sending action into a 'For each' container. This means, that you'll receive an email for every checked option. Maybe there are some restrictions that you can't get many very similar emails at once, and this could lead to have only one email.
The solution is to put your choices' values into a single string, and put this string into the email:
